# Split data using shell

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop

I'm new shell scripting. I need to get data between run and Automatic match counts using shell scripting. So that it can be processed as semi structured data. please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed -n '/run/,/Automatic/p' filename.txt|sed '1d;$d'|sed '$d;s/        //g'` - should clean up data (1st line, 2 last lines, and spaces in beginning)

*shell script - `split.sh`:*

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -n '/run/,/Automatic/p' $1|sed '1d;$d'|sed '$d;s/        //g'
```

*run for any file as below to get output on console and in file:*

```
shell> ./split.sh test.txt |tee splitted.dat
United Kingdom:       21/09/2012
Started:      08/02/2013 16:04:44
Finished:     08/02/2013 16:21:23
Time to process:      0 days 0 hours 16 mins 39 secs
Records processed:    37497
Throughput:   135124 records/hour
Time per record:      0.0266 secs
```

*output will be stored in `splitted.dat` file:*

```
shell> cat splitted.dat 
United Kingdom:       21/09/2012
Started:      08/02/2013 16:04:44
Finished:     08/02/2013 16:21:23
Time to process:      0 days 0 hours 16 mins 39 secs
Records processed:    37497
Throughput:   135124 records/hour
Time per record:      0.0266 secs
shell>
```

***Update:***

```
#!/bin/bash
# p                     - print lines with specified conditions 
# !p                    - print lines except specified in conditions (opposite of p)
# |(pipe)               - passes output of first command to the next
# $d                    - delete last line
# 1d                    - delete first line ( nd - delete nth line)
# '/run/,/Automatic/!p' - print lines except lines between 'run' to 'Automatic'
# sed '1d;s/        //g'- use output from first sed command and delete the 1st line and replace spaces with nothing

sed -n '/run/,/Automatic/!p' $1 |sed '1d;s/        //g'
```

*Output:*

```
Verified Correct:     32426 (86.5%)
Good Match:    2102 ( 5.6%)
Good Premise Partial:   862 ( 2.3%)
Tentative Match:       1039 ( 2.8%)
Poor Match:       4 ( 0.0%)
Multiple Matches: 7 ( 0.0%)
Partial Match:  872 ( 2.3%)
Foreign Address:  2 ( 0.0%)
Unmatched:      183 ( 0.5%)
```

Comment: Thanks! If I need the below output.Verified Correct:     32426 (86.5%)
        Good Match:            2102 ( 5.6%)
        Good Premise Partial:   862 ( 2.3%)
        Tentative Match:       1039 ( 2.8%)
        Poor Match:               4 ( 0.0%)
        Multiple Matches:         7 ( 0.0%)
        Partial Match:          872 ( 2.3%)
        Foreign Address:          2 ( 0.0%)
        Unmatched:              183 ( 0.5%)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/run/,/Automatic/ {//!p }' test.txt
```

This will print all lines (,) between run and Automatic.The //! removes the line run and Automatic match counts from the output.

[image]